# Swing GUI freeze when connecting to ftp server

Tags: java, swing

I am quite new to java and would be very grateful if you could please help me with the below question.

I have an application that connects to a ftp server.  While it connects, i want to display each message receive from the server to a jtextpane.

The problem that i am encountering is that when i click on the connect button, the application freezes and the whole message is displayed at once.  I have tried swingutilies.invokelater, but it does not work.  Please see the codes below.

```
btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    if(validation())
                    {

                        ftpServer = new FTPServer(txtusername.getText(), txtPassword.getText());
                        ftpServer.connectServer(txtSysMsg);

                    }



                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class FTPServer
{
    String username;
    String password;
    FTPClient ftpClient;

    String error;
    String errorType;

    DisplayMessage displayMessage = new DisplayMessage();

    FTPTandem(String user, String pass)
    {

        username = user;
        password = pass;

    }


    public void connectServer(JTextPane txtSys) throws BadLocationException
    {

        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try
        {

            ftpClient.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 21);
            displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" +":"+ftpClient.getRemotePort()+")", "status");


            if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode()))
            {
                displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "Connection established, waiting for welcome message...", "status");
                displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, ftpClient.getReplyString(), "response");
                displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "USER "+username, "command");
                displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "PASS "+password.replaceAll("[\\w\\W]", "*"), "command");

                if(ftpClient.login(username, password))
                {
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, ftpClient.getReplyString(), "response");
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "SYST", "command");
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys,ftpClient.getSystemType(),"response");
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys,"PASV","command");
                    ftpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys,ftpClient.getReplyString(),"response");


                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();

                }
                else
                {
                    displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, ftpClient.getReplyString(), "error");
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();

                }

            }
            else
            {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "FTP server connection refused", "error");

            }



        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            if(ftpClient.isConnected())
            {
                try 
                {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();

                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {

                }

            }

            displayMessage.writeDoc(txtSys, "Cannot connect", "error");

        }

    }




}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;


public class DisplayMessage
{

    public SimpleAttributeSet styleDisplay(String type)
    {
        SimpleAttributeSet style = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
        {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED); 
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Cambria");
            StyleConstants.setBold(style, false);

        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("response"))
        {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, new Color(0,90,0) );
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Cambria");
            StyleConstants.setBold(style, false);
        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("status"))
        {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLACK);   
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Cambria");
            StyleConstants.setBold(style, false);
        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("command"))
        {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.blue);    
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 14);
            StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Cambria");
            StyleConstants.setBold(style, false);
        }

        return style;
    }

    public String messagePrefix(String meg, String type)
    {
        String reply = new String();

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
        {
            reply = "Error:\t"+meg+"\n";

        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("response"))
        {
            reply = "Response:\t"+meg+"\n";
        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("status"))
        {
            reply = "Status:\t"+meg+"\n";
        }
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("command"))
        {
            reply = "Command:\t"+meg+"\n";
        }

        return reply;

    }

    public void writeDoc(JTextPane txtSys, String message, String type) throws BadLocationException
    {

            StyledDocument doc = txtSys.getStyledDocument();        
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), messagePrefix(message,type), styleDisplay(type));


    }

}
```

Comment: You are executing that code in the GUI thread, so the GUI gets frozen until the connection is established. Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and it should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

BackSlash's comment is right on. you should avoid executing code in the GUI thread precisely because it "freezes" the UI until the code finishes. In your case connecting to a remote server is a potentially lengthy operation, that's why you see the UI hang. You should familiarise yourself with the Swing Thread Model, the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and related concepts. Start in [Oracle's own documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and may I suggest the first chapters of the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/), a great book for rich client applications with introductory chapters on all things Swing.

Now for your question, you create a new class extending `SwingWorker` and implement `doInBackground` and `done`. `doInBackground` is executed outside the EDT so it will not block your UI, and done is called once the task is completed. From the docs:

```
final JLabel label;
class MeaningOfLifeFinder extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        return findTheMeaningOfLife();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try { 
            label.setText(get());
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}

(new MeaningOfLifeFinder()).execute();
```

Arguably `findTheMeaningOfLife` is a potentially lengthly operation. It's executed outside the EDIT and, once it's done, it will update the label text with the result by executing `done`.